# What happens if I have two Morsel-Mades on the same floor?

Tags: monster-train

If I have two copies of [morsel-made](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Morsel-Made) (or units infused with its essence on the same floor), what happens when I play a morsel on that floor? Will both be able to eat the morsel with their trigger or will it only apply to one?

Comment: Bounties really ought to be refunded if nobody answers:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like if you have 2 [Train Stewards](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Train_Steward) out, the morsel will be eaten by the front non-morsel unit.
So with two [Morsel-Made](https://monster-train.fandom.com/wiki/Morsel-Made) units, once you place a morsel **only the front one** will eat it and gain its gorge ability.

Source: happened to me once, I obtained a Morsel-Made and duplicated it, but I was not recording, I can try to gain proof later and can update this answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Don't worry about proof- if you have morsel-made you don't want to risk what should be a won run. I only wondered because of the weird interaction between morsel-made and Primordium